# Probability of an event (arrangement with repetition)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a crypted code of $8$ symbols. we define
$$\Omega= \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f\}$$
I want to calculate the probability of the following event: ''having a symbol repeated exactly $2$ times''.
My Idea:

I thought that this is an arrangement with repetition so $$P= \frac{2}{A^2_{16}}=\frac{2}{16^2}$$

Comment: "Having exactly one symbol" or "having at least one symbol"?

Comment: @user exactly two symbols

Comment: That does not answer my question. You mean obviously  the number of repetitions of a symbol. But my question is about the number of groups of repeated symbols.

Comment: Pls show us some examples, both positives and negatives.  E.g. how about $11223344$ or $11234567$ or $11123456$ or $12345671$?